# Is this the right way to allocate memory?

Tags: c, string, malloc, command-line-arguments, allocation

I came across this in someones code... I don't know if it is correct (because even tho it looks wrong, it works). Could someone clarify whether this is correct or not, why so, and why it works anyway ?

---

In short, we want to store all the arguments (given as command-line), concatenated, in 1 string.

*Note: each string has at least 1 character.*

---

*Snippet:*

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // Declaring a pointer to a string
    char *desintation_string;

    // Allocating enough memory to store all arguments (given as command-line) concatenated 
    destination_string = malloc((argc) * sizeof(char));   /* <————— is this correct ? does 
                                                                    it indeed allocate
                                                                    enough memory to fit
                                                                    all the arguments
                                                                    concatenated ? */
    . . . 
}
```

---

The question is:

Does this line "`destination_string = malloc((argc) * sizeof(char));`" allocate enough memory to do so ?

Can someone explain exactly what this is doing ? Cuz I read it as: it is allocating (argc * 1 Byte). Yet, when you run it and copy the arguments to it, it works, could someone explain that too ?

Comment: As long as each string you are receiving has a single character!

Comment: @CinCout .. doesn't this allocate (argc * 1 byte)... how is it enough to store all characters of all arguments ? Or is my assumption wrong ?

Comment: @Lion It does exactly what you think it does.

Comment: The code is wrong. Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Use also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: Ok thanks.. so it is wrong. Just had to make sure.

Answer (score 4):

No. Say your arguments are `"foo" "bar"`. This makes `argc = 2`. With `malloc((argc) * sizeof(char))` you are allocating memory for only 2 chars in this case.

`argv` is a 2D array (hence `argv**`). You need to check length of each argument fist in order to allocate memory for them.

---

What `malloc((argc) * sizeof(char))` does:
`argc` is the number of arguments you pass. `sizeof(char)` returns the number of bytes needs to be allocated for a char variable. So you get `malloc(<number of bytes needed to store argc number of char variables>)`. `malloc()` allocates that number of bytes in the heap.

Comment: AH voila that's what i thought ... it's weird tho cuz when you try to copy the arguments in `dest_str` it works, even like this. Any ideas why ?

Comment: That might work but it is not safe. Might work because the memory addresses next to the allocated memory is not used by any other program at the moment. But that data will be lost in runtime if something starts using that memory because it is free memory as OS sees it.

Comment: @Lion When `malloc` is called, it returns a pointer to *at least* as much memory as requested, but for small allocations, the actual block of memory is often much larger than the requested size. So, even though using more memory than requested is always a bad idea, it doesn't necessarily result in an immediate crash.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you for that explanation. It's all clear now.

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ on virtually any modern operating system your program lives in its own virtual address space, so there's no way you can corrupt other programs' data by writing in memory. What _can_ happen however is that you may overwrite the data structures used for the necessary bookkeeping by the heap, or the next memory block that the heap may have given to another part of your program. By the way, `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, as `sizeof` returns sizes in unites of `char`.

Comment: Yeah @MatteoItalia is correct. Please ignore my comment

Answer (score 0):

> Does this line "destination_string = malloc((argc) * sizeof(char));"
>   allocate enough memory to do so ?

**No**. You need to allocate enough memory. for example here

```
#define BUFSIZE YOUR_EXPECTED_SIZE

destination_string = malloc((BUFSIZE) * sizeof(char));
```

for example command line: `a.out foo bar`

```
snprintf(foo, 1024, "%s - %s\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
```

Comment: Who says 1024 is enough?

Comment: @immibis i know but it's only example purpose.

Comment: Yea it's different everytime.. and could be over 1024, who knows.

Comment: It's not "only example", the *entire point* of this question is what number will be enough. If the question was about something else, then you could use 1024 as an example and say it's up to the reader to replace it with something better, but this question is partly about the 1024.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work for the only a short type of arguments (i.e. `-x`). But for the long type of arguments (i.e. `--list`), it will be failed.

This is how you can do it.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // Declaring a pointer to a string.
    char *desintation_string;
    int Arg_Size = 0;

    // Allocating enough memory to store all arguments concatenated.
    // argv[0] is path not argument given in command line
    for (int i=1, i <= argc, i++)
        Arg_Size += sizeof(argv[i]);

    destination_string = malloc(Arg_Size); 
    . . . 
}
```